# SharePoint Deployed Apps do not work on Web Front End Server

Tags: 2016, add-ins

I have a SharePoint 2016 Farm with 3 Servers. 1 SQL Server, 1 Application and 1 Web Front End Server. When trying to click on a App (under Site Contents) I get "An unexpected error has occurred" and from the ULS Logs I can see the following MEssage before the error occurs:

```
WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://XXXXX:32843/374c2c90cb10479091275218eb3fbfa1/AppMng.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.AppManagement.IAppManagementServiceApplication' Action: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/IAppManagementServiceApplication/GetAppManagementDatabaseMap' MessageId: XXXXXXX'
```

And than:

```
 Exception returned from back end service. 
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: 
The service implementation object was not initialized or is not available. 
(Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by 
IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is: 
System.InvalidOperationException: The service implementation object was not 
initialized or is not available.   
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, 
Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    
at 



System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)    
     at 

  System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)    
     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean 
 isOperationContextSet)).
(with IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)
```

Now comes the strange thing: As soon as I change the webapplication to run on the Application Server, so without calling the WFE all works fine.

I have removed and added subscription settings service application, App management service application and under Service Connections all Proxys are checked.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using SSL? And hostheaders for your webapplications?

Comment: I am not using SSL. The web application is using host headers but i have also a web application without host headers on port 80...

Comment: Allright, that's what i was asking for.. i had problems to get everything to work without that damn "Listener" webapplication without HHS on port 80

Comment: Is the service application added to the webapplication proxy/service group? Go to SharePoint Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage Web Applications, then select your Web Application, and then click in "Service Connections" and check if the related service applications are in the correct group.

Comment: Yes the related service applications are in the correct group and active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a reinstall of sharepoint on the WFE all works fine again.